# Marriage issue, With spouse and HAQQ

Tags: nikah, talaq, husband-wife

I married a non-Muslim while we were both in prison, by way of state.
She converted. I got out, and she reverted back to Christianity.
We have not consummated.
She has years left to serve.
What is the ruling on our marriage and
my rights as a Muslim in this situation.
And yes, I do have feelings for her.
Shukran, I need guidance.